# How to know OS type from the Image in Openstack?

Tags: openstack

If there is an image uploaded in Openstack instance. How can I know the OS of the Image from API call. I curently dont see any attribute to tell the OS type.
Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any guaranteed way of doing this with the existing system. That said, Glance (the openstack service that stores and retrieves images for you), does allow you to put in arbitrary metadata with a given image, so you can "mark it up" any way you like.

Take a look at the glance api (documented at http://docs.openstack.org/developer/glance/glanceapi.html) to get a sense of what's there already and how you can add and read your own attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This how we plan to do. 
We have specified a metadata ex. "os-xxx" as part of each image on Glance server and we collect the details from the metadata to gather the information about the provisioned server.

Do let me know if there is any other way of knowing the details (os type, os version, hardware architecture type etc.) from the provisioned server.